# npm ERR! Cannot read property 'express' of undefined

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, npm-install, npm-package

These are the steps:

1. Create a project.
2. Open Editor.
3. Create a folder called "app1"
4. The app.yaml, index.js, and package.json files are inside "app1" folder.
5. Open a terminal at bottom view of the Editor.
6. Issue a `cd app1` to goto "app1" folder.
7. Issue a `npm install`
8. Issue `gcloud app deploy`
9. Got this error in the terminal:

   File upload done.

   Updating service [default]...failed.

   ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 38fc58ae-73c4-426c-b363-118df7ca4cf3 status: FAILURE

   npm ERR! Cannot read property 'express' of undefined

Any suggestions?

`index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const name = process.env.NAME || 'World';
  res.send(`Hello ${name}!`);
});

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`helloworld: listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "description": "Simple hello world sample in Node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
  "author": "Google LLC",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

`app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: nodejs14
env: standard
instance_class: F1
```

Comment: It's probably a glitch/temporary issue. I just ran your code and successfully deployed to production. I also confirmed that when I opened up https://<project_id>.r.appspot.com/, it displayed 'Hello World'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it by changing the runtime to `nodejs16` in my `app.yaml` file.

Comment: I changed it in functions/package.json -> `"engines": { "node": "16" },` and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run `npm install` in the Cloud Shell. Remove `node_modules` & `package-lock.json` file (if there is one) and run `gcloud app deploy` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in package.json to:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16"
  }
```